# Button não submet ao formulario dentro de um modal

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, button, formulário-submeter

Boa noite, estou com um problema ao submeter um formulário, estou usando o codeIgniter 3 e tenho a seguinte tela:

```
   <!--  modal  -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalArea" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalAreaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> &nbsp; Cadastrar área</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Inicio do formulario  -->
                <form action="<?= base_url('area/insertArea')?>" method="POST" class="form" role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description" class="control-label"> Descrição área <span> <strong>*</strong></span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Ex: Bancos" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Gravar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- final formulario  -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- final modal  -->
```

Como vocês podem ver o *Gravar* está dentro do **form**, porém quando clico não executa nem uma ação, meu controller está assim:

```
class Area extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('Area_Model');

        $this->data['title']      = 'Archive';
        $this->data['complement'] = 'Área';
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('area/index', $this->data);
    }

    public function insertArea()
    {   
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Area', 'required', array('required' => 'o campo %s é obrigatorio'));

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {
            $this->load->view('area/');
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Area_Model', 'area');
            if ($this->area->insertArea($this->session->userdata['session_archive']['company_id'], $this->input->post("description", true))) {
                echo 'ok';
            } else {
                echo 'nao salvou';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

obs: Se eu digitar na URL diretamente ele chega normalmente no controller e faz tudo certo, o problema é o button não submeter, é como se estivesse fora do form mas como vocês podem ver ele está no form.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução, tinha um javascript que por algum motivo não deixava submeter

```
$('#modalArea').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#modalArea #id').val('');
        $('#modalArea #description').val('');
        $('#modalArea').modal();
    });

    $('#tableArea tbody').on('click', '#edit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

apaguei esse trecho e meu codigo funcionou!

Comment: Beleza, mas onde está esse trecho de código na pergunta? Para sua resposta e pergunta terem algum sentido seria necessário que esse trecho constasse na pergunta.